# Add row to inlines dynamically in django admin

Tags: django, admin, inlines

I have the following defined:

```
class AnswerChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AnswerChoice
    # extra = 0


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerChoiceInline]


admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Obviously I get the default extras setting (default is 3). Is there a way built into the admin currently to 'Add another row' to the inline fieldset? So I can fill in say 3 rows, and if I need a 4th I can click a link or button, and have it add an additional row?

Right now my work flow is either set 'extra' to an arbitrarily large number and then just have blank rows or make the user save the model multiple times (so that the extra rows show up).

Comment: I also understand that the 'Save and Continue' sorta does what I want... but seeing if there were any other mechanisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why yes, check out [Add and remove Django Admin Inlines with Javascript](http://www.arnebrodowski.de/blog/507-Add-and-remove-Django-Admin-Inlines-with-JavaScript.html) by Arne Brodowski.

Comment: In my experience that code required some tweaking to get it working with more complex cases, but it's a very helpful start.