# How to embed a model's form in another model in Django?

Tags: django, forms, model

#### UPDATED using Basti's answer view

I have a model for Phones (PhoneMixin - for use with any other model) and for Person:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models

class PhoneMixin(models.Model):
    TYPES_CHOICES = (
        ('HOME', u'Home'),
        ('WORK', u'Work'),
        ('MOBILE', u'Mobile'),
        ('HOME_FAX', u'Fax (home)'),
        ('WORK_FAX', u'Fax (work)'),
        ('PAGER', u'Pager'),
        ('OTHER', u'Other')
    )
    phone_type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=20, choices=TYPES_CHOICES)
    number = models.CharField(_('Number'), max_length=40)
    comment = models.TextField(_('Comment'), blank=True, null=True)

class Person(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Person'
        verbose_name_plural = u'People'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Name')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class PhonePerson(PhoneMixin):
    belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I also have their forms:

```
from django import forms
from models import Person, PhoneMixin

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PhoneMixin
```

And my only view is:

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import PhoneForm, PersonForm


def person_insert_view(request):
    PhoneFormset = formset_factory(PhoneForm)

    if request.method == 'POST':  # If the form has been submitted...
        phone_formset = PhoneFormset(request.POST, prefix='phone_formset')
        person_form = PersonForm(request.POST, prefix='person_form')
        if person_form.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass
            person = form.save(commit=False)
            phone_formset = PhoneFormset(request.POST, instance=person)
            if phone_formset.is_valid():
                phone_formset.save()
                person.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')  # Redirect after POST
        else:
            return render_to_response('function_based_person.html',{
        'person_form': person_form,
        'phone_formset': phone_formset,
    })
    else:
        person_form = PersonForm()
        phone_formset = PhoneFormset(prefix='phone_formset')

    return render(request, 'function_based_person.html', {
        'person_form': person_form,
        'phone_formset': phone_formset,
    })
```

And the function_based_person.html template:

```
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
{% if person_form.visible_fields %}
    {% for field in person_form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="control-group{% if field.errors %} error{% endif %}">
        <label class="control-label" for="id_{{ field.html_name }}">{{ field.label }}    </label>
        <div class="controls">
            {{ field }}
            {% if field.errors %}
            <span class="help-inline">{% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}</span>
            {% endif %}
            {% if field.help_text %}<span class="help-inline">{{ field.help_text }}</span>{% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for phone_form in phone_formset %}
      {{phone_form.as_table}}
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
{% endif %} 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I want to have at least one phone in my Person, and have the possibility to have 2 or more, it the user wants to add it.

Comment: Could you show us the code for your `Person` form?

Comment: Can you show us your view code, and template code then?

Comment: I was missing I had a form.. I updated my code.

Answer (score 2):

A ForeignKey is simply a pointer to specific row in another table. What your `Person` model says is "Every person has one or two telephones. Each telephone is stored in another table called 'Phone'." 
So, unless you are doing something sophisticated, your `Person` form is asking you to associate two *existing* Phones for your new Person.

(editing to respond to your comment).
If what you want to do is to have multiple phones, then what you need is a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/formsets/)

The first thing you need to do is to change which table points at which: instead of the person pointing to a phone, the phone should point to a person. So, for example, add `belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(Person)` to your phone model declaration.

The next step is to actually ask for the phones in your view. Here is where formsets come in. In your views, create a formset:

```
#in views.py
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
PhoneFormset = formset_factory(PhoneForm, extras = 1)

if request.method == 'POST':
    phone_formset = PhoneFormset(request.POST, prefix = 'phone_formset')
    person_form = PersonForm(request.POST, prefix='person_form')
    # validate your forms, etc
else:
    person_form = PersonForm()
    phone_formset = PhoneFormset(prefix = 'phone_formset')
```

Add `phone_formset` to the dictionary passed to your template, end render it as so:

```
# in your template
<form>
{{person_form.as_p}}
{% for phone_form in phone_formset %}
  {{phone_form.as_table}}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

The last thing you need to do is to set each phone's `belongs_to` field to the Person who submitted the form. You will have to do this in your view: maybe save your person *before* saving your phones, get their pk, set the Phone's foreign key and then save it.

Comment: Correct Basti! I don't want to use ForeignKey. It more like a List of Phone. It's no problem for the Phones to be in another table, I don't want to specify the max number of Phone a Person have. I just don't know how to do that...

Comment: Edited to better address your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand this views part.. are you using function-based views? I'm using generic views. I also edited my question for being more clear. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you should use generic views. I suggest you use a view like the one from the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

Comment: I've created a testing application with your answer and updated my models, forms and template. For the sake of completeness, the line in your answer: PhoneFormset = formset_factory(PhoneForm, extras = 1), actually its 'extra' attribute not 'extras'. The problem is that it is showing only one phone using this code. I want to have at least one.

Comment: I also created a Mixin for Phone, so that I can use in any other model.

Comment: Great job. I assume that what you mean by "I want to have at least one" is that you want your user to see a page with one phone's form, and be able to add more dynamically?
If this is the case, there is no easy pre-built way to do this. What most people would do is write some javascript to dynamically add a form, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax. I also found this example on how to do it with no javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448970/django-adding-inline-formset-rows-without-javascript

Comment: I don't need it to be dynamic, just keep it simple (2 phone forms, 1 required). There seems to be a problem when I try to save it.. I get a ValidationError: [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'] =/