# adding inline rows without javascript not adding rows

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to add inline rows without javascript, similar to this SO post: [Django: Adding inline formset rows without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448970/django-adding-inline-formset-rows-without-javascript)

However, when I press add, the form re-initializes and does not add an extra row. What am I doing wrong?

forms.py

```
IndicatorFormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(Disease, Indicator)
```

views.py

```
  disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)  

  if request.method == "POST": 
      if 'add' in request.POST:
        cp = request.POST.copy()
        cp['form-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(cp['form-TOTAL_FORMS'])+1
        indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet2(request.POST, cp, prefix='form')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('drui', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))

  if indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid():
      indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('valdrui', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))

  else:
      indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet2(instance=disease, prefix='form')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update formsets factory to have more forms something like:

```
disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)  

  if request.method == "POST": 
      if 'add' in request.POST:
        cp = request.POST.copy()
        total = int(cp['form-TOTAL_FORMS'])

        #add max_num and extra params to formset factory
        IndicatorFormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(Disease, Indicator, 
                            max_num=total+1, extra=1)

        indicatorInlineFormSet = IndicatorFormSet2(request.POST, cp, prefix='form')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('drui', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to do a work-around to get it to work.

views.py

```
 if indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid() and 'add' in request.POST:
     indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('drui', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))

 elif indicatorInlineFormSet.is_valid():
     indicatorInlineFormSet.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('next_page', kwargs={'disease_id':disease_id}))
```

forms.py

```
 IndicatorFormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(Disease, Indicator, extra=1)
```

Form will validate and reverse back then with extra inlines.