# Django: How to add fields in form from a button without javascript

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I saw a what might be a solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448970/django-adding-inline-formset-rows-without-javascript) but i tried to understand and implement the code on what is indicated in the solution with no avail.

As what I understand( if correct ), in the views, the use of `cp = request.POST.copy()` is to copy what is in the form and then the use of `cp['prim-TOTAL_FORMS'] = int(cp['prim-TOTAL_FORMS'])+ 1` is to add the field but from there I am lost

Sorry for my newbie question because I am **very** new to django.

Any pointers, suggestion, or even a sample code would helpful and much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working to figure this out myself.  The best I could come up with is an a input type="number" and a separate input type="submit" with an "add rows" action.  We can check the add rows with request.POST.get('action') to see if we are submitting for review or adding additional forms.  This is as far as I am currently.  I can read the number input, but when I pass it to the formset_factory via the extra attribute.  Have you solved this?

Comment: I know this is old and really, I haven't solved this one yet but there is a library that might help [here](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset), I used it and works great so far